# Typescript function as a callback for Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, typescript, recaptcha

I have a recaptcha on my page and I'm trying to use the `data-callback` to call an exported TypeScript function. It does not seem to work though unless I use plain Javascript. Here is my Html:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<my key>" data-theme="dark" 
      data-size="normal" data-callback="Landing.enableButton"></div>
```

Here is my Typescript:

```
namespace Landing {
    export function enableButton() {
        alert("Worked!");
    }
}
```

This does not work. I tried this too:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<my key>" data-theme="dark" 
      data-size="normal" data-callback="enableButton"></div>
```

This also does not work. Now if I move it to Javascript, this works:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<my key>" data-theme="dark" 
      data-size="normal" data-callback="enableButton"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableButton() {
        alert("Worked!");
    }
</script>
```

This works as expected. Is there anyway to get this to work using pure Typescript?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and it's automatically compiling my TS file into JS. I am including it from my view like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/pages/landing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can also do this, proving that the TS is valid and being included:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enabledButton() {
        Landing.enableButton();
    }
</script>
```

This works and I get my alert, which is in the TS file, which proves my compiled JS file is being included.

Comment: Try to provide more information like how are you building your ts and how are you including your final js into the html

Comment: I'm running into same issue. @Icemanind Were you able to figure out the solution?

Comment: @user2866746 - No. What I had to do is just use `data-callback="enableButton"` and then inside the `enableButton()` method, call the typescript function.

Comment: @Icemanind that's reasonable workaround. Thanks

Comment: @user2866746 - No problem. If you happen to come across a better solution, please let me know!